# Java Jax-Rs get POST parameters dynamically in runtime like in GET

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'd like to be able to get the parameters passed to the POST request dynamically in runtime, like it can be done with GET.

The parameters I need are defined by one of the parameters passed, I can't know what they are before I read it.

**Example:**

If I pass to a request the param "type=player", I can deduce that the other params passed to this request are "id" and "name", but I can't know it until I read the "type" param.

In another case, the param "type=item" might be passed, and then I can deduce that the other params passed are "quantity" and "quality".

When I use GET, I can use request.getParameter("type") and afterwards understand what other params I'm looking for (request is HttpServletRequest).
e.g. do something like:

```
if (request.getParameter("type") == "player") {
   doSomething(request.getParameter("id"), request.getParameter("name"))
}
else if (request.getParameter("type") == "item") {
   doSomethingElse(request.getParameter("quantity"), request.getParameter("quality"))
}
```

However when I use POST, from what I read so far I must define what parameters I'm expecting to be passed beforehand.

For instance, if the POST consumes JSON, I'll have to specify in the constructor a compiled Java object into which the JSON will be parsed once a request is made.

Since the Java object is defined at compile time, I have no way to dynamically accept and deduce different parameters.

**Is there a way to dynamically access parameters passed to POST the same way it can be done with GET?**

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to get the full body, just by doing this:

```
@POST
public Response go(String requestBody) throws IOException {
    //parse the variable requestBody to get the parameters... 
}
```

The value of the String variable `requestBody` contains all the POST body.

**However to facilitate your life Jersey offers:**

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
    // Store the message
}
```

The keys of in the Map `formParams` are your form POST parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get the following error when I use the MultivaluedMap solution:


com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]]


I'm not writing @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") though. When I do, I get the unsupported media error, even if I add an "Accept" header to the request which is what I found in similar problems.

Comment: It depends  on what are you Posting. If you're Posting JSON that you should send the @Consumes annotation to "application/json", in the above case I've assumed you're posting form data.

Comment: I see. I added a @Consumes json, it seems it works the same with and without, as if Java infers the type in runtime. I'm still getting the error, perhaps I'm not loading MultivaluedMap from the right package?
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]]